# ReactJS: Check if array contains value else append

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components

I'm trying to check if a JSON response contains a value already inside an array and if it doesn't add it in. The problem I'm having is understanding how to approach this in reactjs. I'm checking before I append it but it doesn't want to work. I've tried passing in user `object` & `user.id` but these fail. The attempt below fails to compile but it should help understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8090/v1/users')
    .then(results => {
      return results.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      data.map((user) => (
        if(userList.hasOwnProperty(user.id)) {
          userList.push({label: user.title, value: user.id})))
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` return the resultant array, but you are not returning anything from it, you should instead use `forEach`  Also you need to check if the userList array contains the id, for that you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

What you need is

```
state = {
    userList: [];
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8090/v1/users')
    .then(results => {
      return results.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      const newUserList = [...this.state.userList];
      data.forEach((user) => { // use { here instead of 
        if(userList.findIndex(item => item.value === user.id) < 0) {
          newData.push({label: user.title, value: user.id})
        }
      })
      this.setState({userList: newUserList});
    });
}
render() {
   return (
       {/* map over userList state and render it here */}
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using reduce to turn the returned data into an array you'd like, then adding those values to your existing user list:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8090/v1/users')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => data.reduce((acc, user) => {
  const idList = userList.map(user => user.id);
  if (idList.indexOf(user.id) === -1) {
    acc.push({label: user.title, value: user.id})
  }
  return acc;
},[]))
.then(newList => userList = [...userList, ...newList]);
```